# When redirect from SSLCommerz then success_url: pages can not showing content

Tags: payment-gateway, payment-processing, nodejs-server

[when redirecting URL then showing this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6PuM.png)

My server is nodeJS but when redirecting my specific pages from SSLCommerz[success_url:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLROK.png) I can not show my pages when I hit the redirect URL manually and then show this page info;

Answer (score 0):

Not related to redirection or sslcommerz. You need to define a route which can serve the page at that URL.

Answer (score 0):

ssl commerz is making a post request to get the success route, we normally use get request to get a page, change the request to post for that page and it should work